# Will work be done by magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, work, electromagnetic-induction

lets discuss it in inductor topology?

[image]

A1 and A2 are contacts to the ferrite core of an inductor .DC resistance of ferrite core is of the order of milliohms,the ac resistance is quite high to avoid eddy current losses.

Vdc is applied across the ferrite core with the load connected at its end.
Mdc is the  dc supply applied across the coil of the inductor.

#Direction of current by Vdc#
from A1 to A2

#Direction of magnetic flux lines through Mdc DC magnetization of inductor
from A2 to A1

WILL A STRONG MAGNETIC FLUX REVERSES THE DIRECTION OF CURRENT (from A2 to A1) and
does the work directly in deternining current direction and CAUSES
NEGATIVE RESISTANCE IN THE CORE?SO THE Vdc gets
amplified at the Rload side?

Remember Magnetic field cause the charge carriers to circulate in a particular radius!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Where r is the radius of the path of the charge carrier electron , whose
radius is of the order of 10^10 cm...
v is the velocity of the electron due to electric field.me is the mass of the electron ,q is the charge of the electron and B is the magnetic field in the core.

According to the equation, adjusting electric field (v=mobility*electric field ,by adjusting Vdc) and Magnetic field B, by varying Mdc...if the radius is made equal to radius or less than radius of the electron
then the electron is spinning on its axis (when radius is zero ,its a point, if B tends to infinity,then according to equation ,the radius is zero)..

[image]

According to the table given above...
Meanwhile,according to the analogy,if the electric current equivalent
to magnetic flux in gauss , due to Mdc is made greater than current due to Vdc
i.e., if mmf>emf,
the electrons get accelerated in the opposite direction
as supposed to what will be with Vdc!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).